# Laravel Delete File

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a test.txt file in my Laravel public folder which I simply want to delete from my controller by using

```
unlink('public/test.txt');
```

Whenever I try to run, I keep getting a 'file not found' error

> ErrorException in WidgetController.php line 32:
>   unlink('public/test.txt'): No such file or directory

What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: The problem there is the error itself, which states that the file doesn't exist. (Hint: test != test2)

Comment: How you get the file? Is it from database.. the name of the file?

Comment: @S.I. no, not getting the file name from database now. I'm simply putting the name of the file in the unlink file manually just to check if it gets removed- but it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `app_path` to delete the file. More about the paths [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/helpers#paths)

```
$file_path = app_path("test.txt"); // app_path("public/test.txt");
if(File::exists($file_path)) File::delete($file_path);
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. This guided me to the right path. Just had to change app_path to base_path, since the file in question is in the public folder which is in project base. app_path goes into the app folder

Comment: Glad it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

The public_path function returns the fully qualified path to the public directory and the base_path function returns the fully qualified path to the project root.

So if you want to reach a file in public folder you can use public_path() like this:

```
unlink(public_path("test.txt"));
```

You can also use File:delete instead of unlink like this:

```
use File;
File::delete(public_path("test.txt"));
```